# Report of book titles in sql

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am a new Learner in mySql and I have an assignment to do but I dont get the idea how to solve a question. 
We have two tables Book(ISBN,title,edition,year) and Borrower(borrowerNo,borrowerName,borrowerAddress). borrowerNo is the key for Borrower and ISBAN is the key for Book. The question is asking to produce a report of book titles that have been borrowed by “Peter Bloomfield.”
Now here is where I am confused. How I am going to join these two tables when there is foreign key ?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you share what you've tried?

Comment: from what you have shared - there is no link between the tables. You need the foreign key ISBN to be in Borrower to be able to identify all books borrowed by a specific borrower

Comment: Is not given in the question at all. This is why I am confused too.

Comment: then please post that question? or add isbn to borrower as @gavgrif mention, my friend

Comment: this is what I have: SELECT Book.Title FROM Book INNER JOIN Borrower ON Book.ISBAN = Book.borrowerNo WHERE Borrower.borrowerName = “Peter Bloomfield”;

Comment: so isban and borrower no is same

Comment: @m2j this is all given in question. thats why i can not do it because there no relation between them

Comment: @m2j this is what i assumed. Thats why i say is wrong

Comment: Try: `SELECT *, effort FROM others WHERE homework = 'mine'`

Comment: @Strawberry dont judge ppl when u dont know the truth. How did u know i didnt try. Yes I tried, If I didnt why would I even bother asking help. When people ask for help is called effort. Next time thi nk beofre u write

Comment: @Strawberry Try this: SELECT*, thinking, judge FROM Brain WHERE thinking = 'reasonable' and judge = false; :)

Answer (score 1):

I just googled the question using the text from your post - if these are your tables, then you are using the wrong table to try to link to Borrower:

```
Book (ISBN, title, edition, year)
BookCopy (copyNo, ISBN, available)
Borrower (borrowerNo, borrowerName, borrowerAddress)
BookLoan (copyNo, dateOut, dateDue, borrowerNo)
```

If these are your tables, then it you need to link Borrower to Book Loan (using borrowerNo) rather than to Book and then Book Loan to Book Copy (using copyNo) and then get the book details from Book by linking BookCopy and Book (using ISBN).

Comment: so you can now see that you are using the wrong table to try to get the information and therefore you posted the wrong info inhere. There is no direct link between Book and Borrower - you need to link all the tables listed to get the information

Comment: i used ur advice but I could do it :(

Comment: you need to research how to create a query from joining many tables to get the answer - it is definitely possible using all of the tables. Do some research and then post your query if you are still stuck. The best way to learn stuff is to research it and try it for yourself without being given the answer.